# Error in porting opencv library to pepper_31

Tags: opencv, google-nativeclient

I want to build `opencv` library for `pepper_31` for ARM architecture, but when I am building library with command

`sudo NACL_ARCH=arm make opencv`

below **error** is coming

```
build_tools/naclports.py build ports/opencv
Building 'zlib-1.2.8' [arm]
Building 'libpng-1.6.8' [arm]
Building 'jpeg-6b' [arm]
naclports: opencv-2.4.7: disabled for current arch: arm.
make: *** [opencv] Error 1
```

When I am building library for `pnacl` with command

`sudo NACL_ARCH=pnacl make opencv`

below **error** is coming

```
Wrote script /home/saurav/nacl_sdk/naclports/src/out/repository/zlib-1.2.8/minigzip
./minigzip: line 8: /home/saurav/nacl_sdk/pepper_31/tools/sel_ldr_x86_64: cannot execute binary file
./minigzip: line 8: /home/saurav/nacl_sdk/pepper_31/tools/sel_ldr_x86_64: cannot execute binary file
  *** minigzip test FAILED ***
naclports: Building 'zlib-1.2.8' failed.
make: *** [opencv] Error 1
```

Can any one please suggest how to do it for ARM architecture?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the opencv port was disabled for ARM.  If you like to
look into fixing it you can modify the pkg_info file to re-enable it
and see how/why if fails to build.

Your error is most likely because you have a 32-bit linux install and the
naclports code its trying to run 64-bit sel_ldr tests.  We have an
open issues for this:
https://code.google.com/p/naclports/issues/detail?id=103

For now, you can work around this by using a 64-bit linux install, or
you can modify the "TestStep()" in ports/zlib/build.sh so that it
doesn't try to run the 64-bit tests.